peak integration using trapz but not starting from baseline and visualization
I am trying to integrate signal peaks using numpy.trapz or scipy.trapz. I do manually select the range of a peak min and max. the problem I am facing is that I think these functions integerates the AUC till the baseline. Sometimes my signal start or end is above the baseline. I am open to use a baseline correction method, but I need to visualize the integrated area without any correction to make sure they are correct.
image source:  https://terpconnect.umd.edu/~toh/spectrum/Integration.html

An Example to generate data
import numpy
import peakutils
from peakutils.plot import plot as pplot
from matplotlib import pyplot


centers = (30.5, 72.3)
x = numpy.linspace(0, 120, 121)
y = (peakutils.gaussian(x, 5, centers[0], 3) +
    peakutils.gaussian(x, 7, centers[1], 10) +
    numpy.random.rand(x.size))
pyplot.figure(figsize=(10,6))
pyplot.plot(x, y)
pyplot.title("Data with noise")



If you have signal and you mark min/max, why not calculate integral yourself, without trapz? Also, there are many functions to choose from: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html#module-scipy.integrate

@dankal444 I don't have a function or anything, it's just a curve. Also having a visualization of the actual integration for my research domain

So, what's the question here? Do you have an actual example?

There is data generate in peakutils. I will copy the code and edit the question

Post the actual data as a link (no screenshot).

What do you want to integrate in the example you give?

@PPenton I never said anything about the function. I was talking about numerical computation of the integral, out of digital signal, using some common method

@dankal444 as far as I know, without a function I can only use trapzoid method, which will start from baseline

@jared I need to integrate the second big peak. if I put a range for peak start at 44 and end at 98.

To get the area under the peak you can interpolate the curve using scipy.interpolate.make_interp_spline which has an integrate method. This will be the entire area under the curve between x=a and x=b, so you will then want to subtract the area of the trapezoid created by connecting points at x=a and x=b and the x-axis. In the code I share below I assume f(a) >= 0 and f(b) >= 0.
Note: I added another peak and reduced the noise level to make the endpoints more prominent/obvious.
import numpy as np
import peakutils
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline

plt.close("all")

rng = np.random.default_rng(42)

centers = (30.5, 72.3, 112.1)
x = np.arange(0, 120)
y = (peakutils.gaussian(x, 5, centers[0], 3)
     + peakutils.gaussian(x, 7, centers[1], 10)
     + peakutils.gaussian(x, 6, centers[2], 5)
     + rng.random(x.size)*0.2)
     
peak_indices, _ = find_peaks(-y, prominence=4)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, label="Data")
ax.plot(x[peak_indices], y[peak_indices], "x", color="r", label="End points")
# ax.title("Data with noise")


x1, x2 = x[peak_indices]

interp = make_interp_spline(x, y, k=1)
m = (interp(x2) - interp(x1))/(x2 - x1)
x = np.linspace(x1, x2, 200)
ax.fill_between(x, interp(x), m*(x - x1) + interp(x1), alpha=0.5, 
                label="Desired area")
ax.fill_between(x, m*(x - x1) + interp(x1), alpha=0.5, 
                label="Trapezoid area")

ax.legend()

# Integral under the peak minus the area of the trapezoid connecting the two
# ends of the peak.
# NOTE: EDGE CASE OF PEAK ENDS GOING BELOW THE X-AXIS IS NOT BEING CONSIDERED
integral = interp.integrate(x1, x2) - 0.5*(x2-x1)*(interp(x1) + interp(x2))
print(integral)  # 163.8743118056535



Super neat! Thanks a lot for sharing

just a minor follow up question here. I tried to understand what 0.5*(x2-x1)*(interp(x1) + interp(x2)) is doing. I understand that this part is the integeral of the entire peak. Is there is any reason not to use np.trapz() for this part?

That portion is the area for the orange trapezoid. I would expect np.trapz(y=[interp(x1), interp(x2)], x=[x1, x2]) would give an identical result, although I haven't tested it.
